# Is their any optimised algorithm for finding nth term of tribonacci series (series can go up to 10^18 term)

Tags: numbers, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization, series

I was doing a Microsoft interview problem where the question was to find the Nth term of Tribonacci series where n can be very large(i.e. 10^18) .

I tried implementing  Dp on this problem but as this series is very huge ,couldn't succeeded .

Tried basically the simple technique in which i precalculate the terms upto a certain term and will return the required answer but as N can be upto 10^18 couldn't succedded.

T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3) // T(0)=T(1)=0 , T(2)=1

// if T(n) is big store T(n)= T(n)% 10^9 +7

I know i'm not attempting this problem in a optimised way, any help would be appreciated .

P.S. sorry if any mistake i've done in formatting the question .

Comment: Convert the operation to a matrix multiply, then use repeated squaring to raise the matrix to a power.

Comment: If you have **extremely** high precision floating point arithmetic, there's a closed-form formula, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci type sequences can be converted to raising a matrix to a power, which in turn can be optimized by using repeated squaring. I'm not sure why this was asked in an interview question, since making this connection would require prior knowledge of this method (as I doubt anyone developed such an algorithm in the time span of an interview).

For Fibonacci sequence {0,1,1,2,3,5 ...} , the matrix is

```
M = 1 1
    1 0
```

and F(n+1) = (M^n)[0][0]

For Tribonacci sequence {0,0,1,1,2,4,7,13,...} , the matrix is

```
M = 1 1 1
    1 0 0
    0 1 0
```

and T(n+2) = (M^n)[0][0]

For Tetranacci sequence {0,0,0,1,1,2,4,8,15,...}, the matrix is

```
M = 1 1 1 1
    1 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0
    0 0 1 0
```

and T(n+3) = (M^n)[0][0]

Wiki article for exponentiation by repeated squaring, which reduces the number of loops for n <= 10^18 to about 64.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring